# Do I need to do any maintenance for a wood retaining wall?

Tags: wood, retaining-wall

What do you do to protect your wood retaining wall to stand for extreme weather condition (hot and cold)? I just look at mine and thought that before winter arrive do I need to do something. Is it maintenance free? I don't want to miss anything.

And for the related question, How long the wood retaining wall last (on average)?

Comment: You should only have to visually inspect the wall (once a year or so), and replace/repair any damaged/rotting sections.  As for how long it will last, it depends on what it's built with, how well it's built, drainage in the area, and how well it's maintained.

Answer (score 1):

If it was built correctly (designed with seasonal wood movement in mind) it shouldn't need anything done to it. Depending on how you would like it to look you might want to use a sealer on it. As for how long it will last that all depends on what was used to build it. If it was pressure treated construction lumber then I'd estimate 30+ years although the newer pressure treated formulas haven't been around that long so no one knows for sure how long it will last.